# Rails: Getting wrong selection in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

Here's what I have in the view file:

```
<% users = {'John Doe' => 1, 'Jane Doe' => 2} %>
<% admins = [1,2,nil] %> 

<% i = 1 %>
<% admins.each do |user_id| %>
  <% org_struc_order = 'admin' + i.to_s %>
  <% org_struc_order_text =  'Admin ' + i.to_s%>
  <% if user_id %>
    <%= 'Current selection for ' + org_struc_order_text + ' is '+ users.key(user_id) %>
    <%= select( 'org_selections', org_struc_order, users, {:selected => users.key(user_id)}, { :include_blank => true } ) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= 'Select ' + org_struc_order_text + ' from dropdown' %>
    <%= select( 'org_selections', org_struc_order, users, { :include_blank => true } ) %>
  <% end %>
  <% i = i + 1 %>
<% end %>
```

This is partially working. When the form is displayed, the same value "John Doe" is displaying in the first and second select dropdown boxes, but the caption above it is correct. Above the first box, it says:

```
Current selection for Admin 1 is John Doe
```

and the select box, I have:

```
John Doe
```

Above the second box, it says:

```
Current selection for Admin 2 is Jane Doe
```

but in the select box, I see:

```
John Doe
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with this line I think,

```
<%= select( 'org_selections', org_struc_order, users, {:selected => users.key(user_id)}, { :include_blank => true } ) %>
```

Corrected one:

```
<%= select( 'org_selections', org_struc_order, users, {:selected => user_id}, { :include_blank => true } ) %>
```

You are passing user name Instead of user_id for selected value.

Comment: No. This is the Rails select helper syntax, not HTML. It creates an array named org_selections, sand saves all selected values in it. That part is functioning fine. It's what gets displayed as the selected value that's not correct. I can still select and save fine.

Comment: Here user_id is id of the user rite?

Comment: I have edited the above code. Problem is your select option value is user_id but your passing user name in selected. I hope this will work.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Pl, Mark it as correct answer if you problem solved. Thnx.

Comment: You need to edit your answer and leave only the code, and delete your explanation, as the explanation is incorrect and may mislead someone reading the answer. The correct answer is the code modification you made (which is something I've modified myself a few hours ago, before going to sleep).